# Unique values in data.table list in R

Tags: r, performance, datetime, data.table, bigdata

I am working with a rather large data set (8M obs) and I am trying to obtain unique values/balances for a given date AND not in the previous date/date range.  My date range covers 156 monthly observations. Here is an example of what and how I am proceeding but I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame(ID = c("1234", "5678", "1234", "1112"))
set.seed(1234)
df$Bal = cbind(rnorm(4))
df$Date = as.Date(c("2017-12-31",rep("2018-01-31",3)))
setDT(df)
df[,.(count = uniqueN(ID)), by = Date]
tmp = split(df[,.SD,.SDcols = 1:3], by = "Date")
table(tmp[[2]][,ID] %in% tmp[[1]][,ID])
# FALSE  TRUE 
#   2     1
```

Essentially, 2 FALSE would represent new IDs and 1 TRUE would represent existing.  Additionally, I would like the sum of the balance information.  For example

```
Sum of old balance: -0.1226248
Sum of new balance: -2.068269
```

In turn, my new data frame would be

```
            New_Balance Old_Balance New_Accts Exisiting_Accts
2018-01-31  -2.068269   -0.1226248      2           1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m unclear what you’re asking. What do you mean by your first sentence?

Comment: @Hugh perhaps run the code and read through the posting.  I believe its pretty clear what I'm trying to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below reproduces the expected result for the given sample dataset of two months:

```
library(data.table)
# make sure data is ordered by Date
setorder(df, Date)
# mark first appearance of each ID
df[, Acct := "Old"][rowid(ID) == 1L, Acct := "New"][]
# cumulative balances for each ID
df[, Balance := cumsum(Bal), by = ID][]
# reshape from long to wide format
dcast(df, Date ~ Acct, fun = list(sum, length), value.var = "Balance")
```

> ```
>          Date Balance_sum_New Balance_sum_Old Balance_length_New Balance_length_Old
> 1: 2017-12-31       -1.207066       0.0000000                  1                  0
> 2: 2018-01-31       -2.068268      -0.1226246                  2                  1
> ```

Note the code needs to be verified against a more elaborate sample dataset containing more months.

Comment: this worked really well for the 8M obs!  However, I did have to change it a little in order to make it work.                                                                                                             `setorder(df, AS_OF_DATE) df[rowid(ID) == 1L, Acct := "New"][]
df[,Balance := cumsum(Balance), by = ID]
dcast.data.table(df, Date ~ Acct, fun = list(sum, length), value.var = "Balance")`  Using the above only gave me the sum and frequency for a given date for all of the accounts.  Any ideas?